# Unity.MVC ASP.Net Controller Constructor not Called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm attempting to use the latest version on Unity.Mvc but for some reason my controller never gets called. I have the following controller

```
public class AdminApiController : ApiController
    {
        private IUserRepository userRepository;

        public AdminApiController(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        [Route("api/AdminApi/{lastName}/{currentUserId}")]
        public IEnumerable<UserDetail> GetUsers(string lastName, string currentUserId)
        {
            return userRepository.Search(lastName, currentUserId)
                .Select(u => new UserDetail { Id = u.Id, Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName });
        }

    }
```

and the latest version of Unity.Mvc appears to use a `UnityWebActivator` class to set up the container, i.e.,

```
public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

and in my unity config I have the following

```
public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
        /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            // container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your types here
            // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

            container.RegisterType<IUserDatabase, UserDatabase>();
            container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        }
    }
```

which registers my in-memory repo, i.e.,

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        IUserDatabase db;

        public UserRepository(IUserDatabase db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> Search(string lastName, string currentUserId)
        {
            if (Exists(currentUserId))
            {
                return GetByLastName(lastName);
            }

            return new List<User>();
        }

        private IEnumerable<User> GetByLastName(string lastName)
        {
            return db.Users.Where(u => u.LastName == lastName);
        }

        private bool Exists(string id)
        {
            return db.Users.Any(u => u.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

where

```
public class UserDatabase : IUserDatabase
    {
        private User[] users = new User[]
                       {
                        new User("1", "John", "Smith"),
                        new User("2", "Fred", "Smith"),
                        new User("3", "John", "Doe")
                       };

        public IEnumerable<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return users;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I start the application I can see that my types are being registered using breakpoints, but when I put a breakpoint in the constructor of `AdminApiController` it never gets called. Subsequently the controller is never created and I get an Internal Server error when I try to use the controller.

What am I missing with the setup to ensure `AdminApiController` is instantiated and being injected with objects from the container?

Comment: What is the internal server error that you get?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Have you got a line that looks like this somewhere: `[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebDirectory.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]`?

Comment: Yes at the top of `UnityMvcActivator` this does appear to kick things off when the application starts.

Comment: You are using the Unity.Mvc package, but I notice your controller inherits ApiController. If this is a WebAPI, perhaps you could try using the Unity.WebAPI package.